# Yii2 mpdf, add image to second page of PDF file

Tags: yii2, mpdf

I already have a `.pdf` file. I need to add uploaded image by user (converted then to `base64`) to second page of PDF file or any other page, and put image by coordinates of page. Then resave base PDF file.

How can i do this?

I use `Mpdf` in `Yii2`. On a front - `jquery`

Comment: please see [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question

Answer (score 0):

I was find the answer by my self.

```
        $pdf = new Mpdf();

        $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile(_PATH_FOR_PDF_FILE_);
        //Here I get array with images params (You can see this params in mPDF doc) - THIS IS MY CUSTOM FUNCTION!!!
        $images = $document->getImagesForPdf();

        for ($i = 1; $i <= ($pageCount); $i++) {
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $import_page = $pdf->ImportPage($i);
            $pdf->UseTemplate($import_page);

            $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($import_page);

            //Here I create an image with the parameters that I received above on current page
            $pdf->Image($images[$i]);
        }

        $output = $pdf->Output($name, $destination);
```